# Laravel: How to Get All Orders of Customers Assigned to a Specific Agent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I've been pulling my hair strings for days now trying to write this query but just not getting anywhere. I have these tables:

```
Agents (Users)
  id
  name
  email
  password
  created_at
  updated_at

Customers
  id
  agent_id
  firstname
  lastname
  email
  created_at
  updated_at

Orders
  id
  customer_id
  product_id
  amount

Customer_Tags
  id
  customer_id
  name

Products
  id
  name
```

I need to write a SQL statement that gets all Orders of Customers who are assigned to the current logged in user (by agent_id) and has this tag (ID: 234) but not any of these tags [3343, 445, 333] and has purchased any of these product (IDs: 18, 33, 29).

Just so you understand what tags do. Customers are tagged based on the actions they takes. This is done for marketing purposes. If a customer purchase a product, that customer gets a specific tag attached to them. If they go on to do take another actions like watching the webinar, there's another tag attached and on and on.

The application is built on the Laravel framework. I tried using the built-in Eloquent ORM.

```
return Order::with('customer')
    ->whereHas('customer', function (Builder $query) {
        $query->where('agent_id', Auth::id());
      })
      ->whereHas('customer.tags', function (Builder $query) {
        $query->whereIn('id', [234])
          ->whereNotIn('id', [3343, 445, 333]);
        })
        ->whereHas('product', function (Builder $query) {
            $query->whereIn('id', [18, 33, 29]);
          })
          ->get();
```

It works by pulling the orders of all customers that has tag ID 234. However, it's also including orders of customers of has any of these tags (3343, 445, 333) as well which is the opposite of what I want.

I also tried using the built-in Query Builder and got the same results.

```
return DB::table('orders')
        ->join('customers', 'orders.custom_id', '=', 'customers.id')
          ->join('customer_tags', function ($join) {
              $join->on('customers.id', '=', 'customer_tags.customer_id')
                ->whereIn('customer_tags.id', [234])
                  ->whereNotIn('customer_tags.id', [3343, 445, 333]);
              })
              ->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'orders.product_id')
                ->whereIn('orders.product_id', [18, 33, 29])
                  ->where('customers.agent_id', Auth::id())
                    ->select('orders.invoice_at', 'customers.*', 'products.name')
                      ->get();
```

Please help. Right now, I'm just open to a anything. Whether is Eloquent ORM, Query Builder or just a clear SQL statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just add the `tags` clause into the `customer` query and use [whereDoesntHave](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence)?

```php
Order::with('customer')
    ->whereHas('customer', function ($query) {
        $query
            ->where('agent_id', Auth::id())
            ->whereHas('tags', function ($query) {
                $query->whereIn('id', [234]);
            })
            ->whereDoesntHave('tags', function ($query) {
                $query->whereIn('id', [3343, 445, 333]);
            });
    })
    ->whereHas('product', function ($query) {
        $query->whereIn('id', [18, 33, 29]);
    });
```

Also, you can use `->toSql()` to see the final SQL query to see if it's what you need.

Comment: you're a genius. You just solve the problem I've been beating beating myself up for days. I even posted it in the Laracast forum and no one on there could help. Thanks my friend. How can I include customers without tags as well?

Comment: @lotsonj No problem. You can simply add a `orDoesntHave('tags')` on the customer query.